# Why am I getting .clear() is not a function while clearing a datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm getting the error below:

> getdata.js:96 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable(...).clear is not a function

When I use the following code:

```
$("#dynamic-table").dataTable().clear();
```

Although the function works fine and clears the datatable but I get an error in console

Comment: It's `DataTable()`, not `dataTable()`: https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear()

Comment: :)...  upvote ;)

Comment: I don't know what is the version of datatable I'm using but I'm working on a admin template where it is working fine with `dataTable()` and not `DataTable()`.Both of them are giving the same error.

Comment: Are you sure `$("#dynamic-table")` has data when you run that code? can you add `console.log($("#dynamic-table"))` right before that line and put the output in your question?

Comment: It is removing the data but an error pops up in console.log. Nothing working in console after that code.

Comment: Comment the code, insert console.log instead. btw are you sure the error is for that line?

Comment: Yes I'm sure for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

example from the jsfiddle below, deleting all content from  (on a paginated table!).

```
$("#delete").click(function() {
dataTable.fnClearTable();
dataTable.fnAddData([
    'new engine',
    'new browser',
    'new platform',
    'new version',
    'new css'
]);
});
```

you should use like `$('#table').dataTable().fnClearTable();` and aslo check js fiddle

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manish1226/9kLmb9fu/227/)

Comment: It worked but please add where my problem was  because I might face similar problem later on due to the same reason

Comment: When a dataTable is instantiated with DataTable() which returns an API instance var dataTable = $('#example').DataTable(); and use .clear please see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/manish1226/9kLmb9fu/232/

Comment: and also please up the ans.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

$("#dynamic-table").DataTable().clear();

Comment: I already specified in the comment both DataTable and dataTable are giving the same error

Comment: Probably in this case you are using the old style API with a new style API object.

Comment: Yes I'm guessing the same

Answer (score 3):

dataTable() and DataTable() both functions are different. If you want to clear your data-table then use this code.

> `$('#myTable').DataTable().clear().draw();`

Comment: Information shared is useful. Thank you